# How to enable collisions in matter.js?

Tags: javascript, p5.js, matter.js

I'm trying out *matter.js* on *p5.js*.
I'm trying to make a simple Top Down simulation where bodies collide with each other when trying to move.

Here's my code:

```
let engine,world;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  engine = Matter.Engine.create();
  world = engine.world;

  m1 = Matter.Bodies.rectangle(50,50,50,50);
  m2 = Matter.Bodies.rectangle(100,50,50,50);
  Matter.World.add(world,m1);
  Matter.World.add(world,m2);
}

function draw() {
  background(220);

  Matter.Body.translate(m1,{x: 1,y: 0});
  pos1 = m1.position;
  pos2 = m2.position;
  rectMode(CENTER);
  rect(pos1.x,pos1.y,50,50);
  rect(pos2.x,pos2.y,50,50);
}
```

My intention was to make body m1 push body m2 when trying to move in his direction. Unfortunately m1 is just going through m2. How do I make them collide?
I've seen that I can add stiffness to the body's options but I don't think that will help me if they are not colliding in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found the problem: the translate function won't ever check collisions. Instead I used the setVelocity function and updated the engine every frame.

```
Matter.Engine.update(engine);
Matter.Body.setVelocity(m1,v1);
```

I also had to turn off the gravity in the setup.

```
engine.world.gravity.y = 0;
```